# Como é feito um "Tour 360º"?

Tags: aplicação-web

Eu gostaria de saber como é o processo de desenvolvimento de um tour 360º.

[Clique aqui para ver o exemplo](http://www.webtour360.com.br/?abre=fotos=panoramicas=360=tour=virtual=360=foto==exemplos)

Creio um "sistema" desses não é feito toda na "mão grande", de uma forma primitiva, linha por linha.

Quais ferramentas são utilizadas?
Existe um software que gera tudo?
Como é feito?

Comment: no link que passou é feito em flash. Infelizmente não podemos mais usar o flash, mas há soluções em html  e javascript

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O mercado de vídeos 360º ainda é incipiente, e não existem muitos padrões de indústria.

Isso dito, as plataformas emergentes são parecidas em alguns aspectos. Por exemplo, a captura do vídeo ocorre com dispositivos que cobrem o máximo possível da esfera de foco ao redor da cena:

- Sphericam 2
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- GoPro Six-Camera Spherical Solution
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A disposição das câmeras é proposital. Observe como os focos individuais se encaixam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A seguir, softwares como o [Autopano](http://www.kolor.com/autopano-video/) compõem um vídeo que é o resultado da mescla sincronizada das várias câmeras.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O mesmo pode ser feito com imagens estáticas, utilizando ferramentas como o [Microsoft Image Composite Editor](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/ice/) ou [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/); seus resultados podem ser vizualizados via ferramentas como o [krpano Panorama Viewer](http://krpano.com/).

Comment: Sobre a tecnologia aplicada na câmera já li alguns materiais a respeito. A dúvida realmente é a respeito sobre a mesclagem-sincronização das imagens. Um dúvida, o **Autopano** é somente para vídeos? Um tour 360º **somente de imagens** é feito da mesma forma? Caso não, quais softwares são capazes de fazer isso e também gerar o _Visualizador_ do tour?

Comment: @Zkk post autalizado com respostas à suas perguntas.